# Sql Report sever Switch Expression not giving the correct results

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hi I have an Switch expression on a textbox to give a percentage:

```
=Switch(

    Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value) = 0 AND 
    Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) = 0, 0,

    Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value) = 0 Or
        Sum(fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) = 0, 1,

    Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) > 0 AND Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value) <> 0,
        ABS(Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) / Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value))

)
```

Basically if both TheoCostPriceValue and VarianceCostPriceValue are 0 then the result should be 0, if either of them is 0 then it should be 1.
If both of them are not 0 I will check to see if the VarianceCostPriceValue is positive or negative and then do the correct calculation.

My problem is that when I have a TheoCostPriceValue of 0 and a VarianceCostPriceValue of 2.35 the expression returns #Error, rather then 100% (which is what I expect).

I can't see any issues with my switch, however why would it return #Error rather then 100%?

I'm using SQL Reporting service 2008.

After some experimenting, I found that it only returns #Error after adding:

```
ABS(Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) / Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value)),
```

Before that it works fine, and if I turn this into a value like 0.5 it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems to be a bit of a strange one, even though I'm checking to see if TheoCostPriceValue is not 0, it still seems to be passed through somehow.

I updated the Expression to this:

```
=Switch(

Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value) = 0 AND Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) = 0,
    0,

Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value) = 0 OR Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) = 0,
    1,

Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) > 0 AND Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value) <> 0,
    ABS(Sum(Fields!VarianceCostPriceValue.Value) / 
    IIF(Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value) = 0, 
        1, 
        Sum(Fields!TheoCostPriceValue.Value))))
```

and it started working.

I don't know why this happens but it seems that making sure the TheoCostPriceValue can't be 0 fixed it.